# Importing NetBeans project to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, import

So I need to import my NetBeans project to Eclipse and so far I have done:

- Loaded up Eclipse:
- File--New--Java Project--Import--Archive File
- Selected my zipped folder and imported.

Now I have the source files imported, when I try to run it, it says `The selection cannot be launched, there are no recent launches`?

I do have a package installed, my project is called lab 9 so I have `package lab9` in every class so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

-